# Can you install Visual Studio 2008 Pro and Team System side-by-side?

Tags: jquery, ajax, visual-studio-2008

I have a couple of question for you..

Can I install on the same machine visual studio 2008 Professional and Team System ?

the reason is because with Team System already installed I receive an error when I work with ajax and jquery:

```
Error   1   Error updating JScript IntelliSense: Client-side script IntelliSense information was not generated due to an error in an external script reference. Y:\TestTemp\WebSite1\Default.aspx   1   1   Y:\TestTemp\WebSite1\
```

so I thought maybe my installation is corrupted ? I tried  to install the web express edition on same machine and works fine as well with ajax.
Do you know if I can install the professional version as well on the same machine?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would try to fix the JavaScript Intellisense. (If you have team system, I would try to use it). The [Visual Web Developer Team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2007/07/30/workaround-for-beta-2-javascript-intellisense-and-colorization-issue.aspx) has a fix for one (registry) problem that could cause this behavior.

Have you tried to repair the install?

Answer (score -1):

In answer to your question, no you cannot install two editions side-by-side.

Comment: Wrong, you can install different SKUs of the same version side by side.